# Is it permissible to donate ones body organs?

Tags: halal-haram, practical-islam, medical, sadaqah, human-body

We have the technology and practices that can successfully transplant organs from one human to another. This practice saves thousands of lives, but the problem is the lack of resources; organs.

There are line-ups of people waiting for an organ donation, and these people often know that if they do not receive a replacement organ, their life will end. Hence the reason why I'm asking the question:

Is it permissible in Islam to donate ones organs? To be more precise, is it permissible to notify that **after death**, if your organs are functional, they can be used to save other people's lives?

I'd like to also hear the answer about donating an organ while alive (for example, someone giving up a kidney to save a family member's life).

Comment: Maybe u should include which sect ur interested in....

Comment: Yes. I am not sure why such a question even begs a "Islamic" answer. Logically and rationally, why would god with infinite power care about your physical organs after death? It's not like they physically "travel" to the afterlife. There are thousands of people (especially children) who are in constant danger, some even terminal unless they receive an organ. Any "scholar" who tells you otherwise has forgone all critical thinking and is most likely misinterpreting whatever source he is using.

Comment: @masfenix Its important as human beings to consider listening to other opinions no matter what our own views, or critical conclusions are. Its a sign of openness and willingness to improve ones perspective.

And your comment was far from being beneficial, nobody ever suggested that our organs "travel to the afterlife". Also, I already mentioned that there are thousands of people who need an organ donation to survive, and hence my interest in asking this question.

Cheers mate :)

Comment: @servant-of-Wiser Well, I'm a Sunni, but I'm not really a fan of this whole sect thing. All I want is an answer from an Islamic point of view, the way I saw it was that donating the organs would save people's lives which is a commendable thing to do, but was wondering if there is another way of looking at it, if essentially giving away parts of our bodies isn't acceptable.
Do questions like these have different answers based on sects? So things that aren't directly taken from the Quran & only based on interpretations, can change based on the sect?
(Sorry I'm new here)
Thanks for your response.

Comment: @Amrito10 The SE network isn't a place to get a different perspective as opinion/truth based questions are not allowed here. It is meant to be a repository of critical and objective QA. Thus, the question posed by you is essentially asking for a conclusive "yes/no" answer. I commented (not as an answer form) saying that whatever answer you receive here will highly be dependent on a person (whether its a scholar or else) viewpoint. I simply raised the point that these "opinions" should not really exist. Consider the answer below...

Comment: ... The answer is based on arbitrary rules which may or may not apply in today's time and worldview, may not have any medical or scientific backing, and may heavily be influenced by the cultural norms and  traditions. I guess I should mention this that I am registered with my country as an organ donor. I never 'thought' about a 'opposing' 'opinion' in the religious context as it really makes no sense to have one.

Comment: @masfenix No you did not "simply raise the point that these "opinions" should not exist", you slated me for even asking the question.

And I was interested in knowing if it is clearly stated in Islam whether it is ok or not to donate ones organs. If there isn't any significant proof dismissing the practice, I will gladly register myself too. Its the only reason why I even asked the question here, I don't think it did any harm.

Comment: @Amrito10 Actually, my apologies. I didn't mean it as a rude remark and definitely didn't mean to cause offense. My intentions were to raise the point but re-reading my comment, my specific wording was not correct. Again my apologies!

Comment: @masfenix No problem my friend, it happens, have a wonderful day !

Answer (score 1):

In regard to this question which could be considered as an approved practice, there seems to be some viewpoints which apparently are not precisely the same, but could be considered as a permissible act by observing some conditions.

For instance I term two of them (from the viewpoint of some Shi'a scholars or Marja’al-Taqlids) which hopefully could be profitable for you.

> The office of the Grand Ayatollah Khamenei:
>
> If the organs of the donors are used for the cure of other patients,
>   but quicken their death, it is impermissible, other than that, if the
>   surgery is done with the donor’s permission or another ‘muhtaram’
>   person’s life depends on it, it is permissible.
>
> The office of the Grand Ayatullah Makarem Shirazi:
>
> It is permissible, given that all necessary conditions are met.

---

**Reference:**

[www.islamquest.net](http://www.islamquest.net/fa/archive/question/fa3116)

Comment: Thank you for your response. It makes sense that anything that is potentially detrimental to our own health should not be done.
Is there really a difference in this case between Sunni/Shia answers?
Basically is there anything that mentions that we need to keep our bodies in the same state at which we passed in, or something similar, and would thus disapprove with this practice?

Comment: @Amrito10, I'm not aware well regarding dear Sunni brothers Fatwas, but as I searched limit in Sunni's sites, I found it the same as Shia to some extent. Actually as I saw, there seems to be some conditions in allowing that from the view of Sunni brothers as well.